# Optimization AP Calculus problem

Tags: calculus

Determine the point on the function $Y=(x-3)^2-1$ that is closest to the point $(-4,-3)$.

---

I used distance formula and got:

> - $d=x^4-12x^3+59x^2-124x+137$
> - $d'=4x^3-36x^2+118x-124$

I don't know how to factor from here if I have done the problem correctly so far.

Comment: It decreases on this segment.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: so, hi, what's the specific thing you need help with?

Comment: I used distance formula and got  d=x^4-12x^3+59x^2-124x+137. then I took the derivative and got 4x^3-36x^2+118x-124.  I don't know how to factor from here if I have done the problem correctly so far.

Comment: Hint: the point $(a,b)$ satisfies the relation that the line through $(-4,-3)$ and $(a,b)$ is orthogonal to the graph at $(a,b)$.

Comment: @cynthia you should have included this in the original post so others can see where you encountered trouble and how to guide you back on track.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: I second that. The OP would be better if it included the attempt at solving the problem!

Comment: Hint#2: move the whole thing 3 steps left and 1 step up. The problem becomes to minimize the distance from $(-7,-2)$ to $y=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**DISCLAIMER:** I originally made an error in my calculations. The expressions you gave are in fact correct. By using the squared distance formula we have:
$$
\begin{align}
d(x) &=(-4-x)^2+(-3-f(x))^2 \\
&=x^4-12x^3+59x^2-124x+137
\end{align}
$$
This has derivative:
$$
d'(x)=4x^3-36x^2+118x-124
$$
and second order derivative:
$$
d''(x)=12x^2-72x+118
$$
This quadratic polynomial has its vertex at $(x,y)=(3,10)$ and since the leading coefficient is positive this implies that $d''(x)\geq10$ and $d'$  has only a single zero.

Now since $d'(0)=-124$ and $d''(x)\geq10$ we only have to look for positive values $x\in(0,12.4]$. Furthermore $d'(1)=-38$ and $d''(1)=58$ and decreasing so the zero appears to be nearby.

---

BTW the perpendicular slope approach suggested by a user in the comments yields (essentially) the same cubic equation:
$$
\frac{-4-f(x)}{-3-x}\cdot f'(x)=-1\iff d'(x)=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Like other users have said, the distance formula is the way you want to go. 
Since we want to find the shortest distance between a point on the function and the point $(-4,-3)$ we have to somehow incorporate the distance formula. So we begin by first taking what we know and putting that into the formula. Namely,

$$f(x) = (x-3)^2 - 1$$

$$distance = \sqrt{((x-(-4))^2 + (f(x)-(-3))^2}$$

$$or$$

$$distance = \sqrt{(x-(-4))^2 + (((x-3)^2 - 1)-(-3))^2}$$

We now have a function to optimize!

So that is what we do (i.e take the derivative and set equal to zero).
We note that the derivative of any square root function ($f(x)$) of another function ($g(x)$) will yield

$$\frac {g'(x)}{\sqrt{f'(g(x)}}$$

And when we set that equal to zero and solve only the numerator will matter, 
$g'(x)$. So, we have

$$g(x) = (x-(-4))^2 + ((x-3)^2 - 1)-(-3))^2$$

$$or$$

$$g(x) = (x+4)^2 + (x-3)^4 - 4(x-3)^2 +4$$

So the derivative is:

$$g'(x) = 2(x+4) + 4(x-3)^3 - 8(x-3)$$

or after some work:

$$g'(x) = 4x^3-36x^2+118x-124$$

And we can factor this (using the rational root theorem) to be:

$$g'(x) = (x-2)(4x^2-28x+62)$$

Since we are optimizing:

$$(x-2)(4x^2-28x+62) = 0$$

Which only has the real solution of $x = 2$.
We plug this into our $f(x)$ and we get that the closest point is $(2,0)$.
Again we can check this answer to see if we are even close to right by using any graphing utility.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fd8pyqknhw

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for answering this question!! This is a huge help!